Intermittent Firefox Installation Failure in Docker CI
I have a docker image to install firefox, that runs as expected locally but fails intermittently on CI. Firefox doesn't get installed, this is what I am doing.
FROM node:20
RUN wget -O firefox.tar.bz2 "https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=linux64&lang=en-US" --no-check-certificate
RUN tar -xvf firefox.tar.bz2
RUN sudo mv firefox/* /usr/bin/

Jenkinsfile looks like this, no extra arguments
def dockerImage = docker.build("build-image:${env.BUILD_ID}", "--build-arg DOCKER_UNAME=${env.DOCKER_UNAME} --build-arg DOCKER_UID=${env.DOCKER_UID} --build-arg DOCKER_GID=${env.DOCKER_GID} -f Dockerfile .")


Welcome to DevOps! Can you mention the image used in your Dockerfile?? Edit your question to add that info.

@Ajay just using node:20 and these steps

I tried your Dockerfile with some minor changes so that my container won't stop. The Firefox browser is installed inside the container and I guess the issue will be with your CI. Can you provide any logs in your Jenkins CI which can be used to know the steps that are being taken place??
